# How to send a custom email when google form is submitted?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a google form, what I want is everytime a user submits form it will email to everyone@company.com, with the content let's say:

```
<img src="image.jpg" />
<p>Hi everyone, I am {{form_field1}}</p>
```

I found an add-on "Email Notifications for Forms", and it's working, the problem is, its only limited 20 email notifications per day.

Does anyone knows here how to send email notification for free? I think its possible to use the "Script editor", but I don't know the syntax how to do this.

Comment: There are numerous email examples on SO. Do some research and take a look at [ask].

Answer (score 0):

let's try cross platform.
if you use a Line app, you can create a BOT with an Apps Script based webhook.
Use that Messaging API, push to your id or group and feel free to get notif